# Stripe force validation for only LinkAuthenticationElement

Tags: validation, stripe-payments

I'm using a Stripe LinkAuthenticationElement in React, and I'd like to force validation on it early, so I can bind the email address with my checkout session when I create a PaymentIntent.

The only way I can find to force validation on the email is by calling `elements.submit();`, but this also prematurely performs validation on the payment fields. The best I've found is calling `clear()` on the payment method after doing an early `submit()`

Is there some other way to get stripe to show `Your email address is incomplete.` besides calling `elements.submit()`?

Comment: I don't quite agree with attempting to bind the email address early before the user actually clicks submit. What if the user checks, and then discovers that they made a mistake in their email address?

If what you intend to is actually to update the value as the customer keys it in, you can consider using the onChange event instead : https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_change?type=linkAuthenticationElement. There is a `complete` parameter also, but that doesn't indicate that the customer is done keying in their email.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps the deferred flow might suit your use case better? https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred

Comment: @alex I'm using the deferred flow. This is mainly just about being able to use the LinkAuthentication element, to have a consistent UX and be able to use Link, instead of my own email field. I'm going to make it so that a checkout session can be updated after payment intent is created.. I mainly just want to guarantee that every checkout session ALWAYS has an email. So I don't want it to be possible to create a payment intent without one.